# aspnet-user-identity in filename, but it doesn't always work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

The website will use Cookie Authentication.  So, here's an example of something in my nlog.config (I'm possibly interested in using NLog):

```
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\${aspnet-user-identity}-nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\${aspnet-user-identity}-nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>
```

For both entries, look at ${aspnet-user-identity}.

Once the user logs-in, everything will be written to MyUserName-nlog-all-2019-04-03.log.  That way I can log per User.

What I am seeing is that even though I am logged-in, there's certain things that DON'T get written to MyUserName-nlog-all-2019-04-03.log.  They are instead written to -nlog-all-2019-04-03.log. Notice the leading dash?  And No UserName? I mean, most does get written to "MyUser", but there's some things that don't.

My little test project has an Account Controller/View for logging in and then a simple Controller/View they are directed to once they have logged in.

Imagine getting to the login page, logging in, and getting directed to your first page.  Well, after that small test, I see this -nlog file with this written in it (and this is after they are logged in):

```
    2019 - 04 - 03 15:53:39.2429 | 2 | INFO | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker | Executed action method TestApp1.Controllers.AccountController.Login(TestApp1), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult in 2263.1283ms.
    2019 - 04 - 03 15:53:39.2490 | 1 | INFO | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult | Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /.
    2019 - 04 - 03 15:53:39.2490 | 2 | INFO | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker | Executed action TestApp1.Controllers.AccountController.Login(TestApp1) in 2306.6386ms
    2019 - 04 - 03 15:53:39.2490 | 1 | INFO | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware | Executed endpoint 'TestApp1.Controllers.AccountController.Login (TestApp1)'
    2019 - 04 - 03 15:53:39.2490 | 2 | INFO | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost | Request finished in 2328.4375ms 302
    2019 - 04 - 03 15:53:39.2490 | 1 | INFO | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost | Request starting HTTP/ 1.1 GET http://localhost:61610/   
    2019 - 04 - 03 15:53:40.3210 | 1 | INFO | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost | Request starting HTTP/ 1.1 POST http://localhost:61610/HomeController/Read application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 20
```

Why does this happen?  And how do I get everything written to the "Users" specific file (after they've been logged-in)?

Comment: Sounds strange to use GDC for storing the active userid. GDC-items are intended to be semi-stable during application lifetime. Your application only has one user? Maybe consider using MDLC.

Comment: I removed the info about GDC, I thought it was distracting.   But I wasn't using GDC to store the active userid.  That might be a misunderstanding.  ... As for Users: there will be many.

Comment: Based on what you have posted here, there is a redirect happening; RedirectToAction is returned. Redirects usually drop all cookie information. Therefore, the user isn't known. There are likely other things getting logged by the application where the user context isn't known at the time. Nature of the beast.

Comment: @R.Richards I see.  For example, it's a small app that does nothing.  So another test for me was to click refresh on the browser.  And it would add some lines to the "blank" log file.  So I'm guessing that's another instance of the app dropping cookies?  Hrmm.  Darn beast, and it's nature!

Comment: Similar, yes. The application will not know the context right away when a refresh happens. Eventually it will, then the logging will work as desired. You will always have situations where the user context isn't known. Like, before the user logs in.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time.  If you want to split out your comments into an answer, I will green check-mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have posted here, there is a redirect happening; `RedirectToAction` is returned. Redirects drop all cookie information, therefore the user isn't known right then.

You will always have situations where the user context isn't known. Like when a user comes to the site, but before they log in.